# manipulating table row colours when click and hover, conflicting when using zebra row colours

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with many rows, using jQuery im capturing the click and hover to then change the colour using add and remove class. When you click the row is highlighted as green and when you hover the row is highlighted pink.

```
$("#div2 tr").click(function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('highlight2');  
    $(this).addClass('highlight2');
});

$('#div2 tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight1');
}, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('highlight1');        
});

.highlight1 {
    background-color: #FFD6F5;
}
.highlight2 {
    background-color: #CEF6CE;
}
```

What im also wanting to do is zebra the rows, using a 2 tone gray, however when i do this with additional CSS it then prevents the above from working, and beleive a clash is accouring, due to my lack of CSS im unable to work this out hence requre some help or pointing in the right direction if possible.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #F2F2F2}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FAFAFA}
```

Comment: Highlight class background color css error? You missed the # for color code, or is it a typo?

Comment: This is a demo using css only, click and hold the row to see the color on click. http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/uv7csbec/

Comment: @abhiklpm - Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: @abhiklpm, when clicked im wanting the colour to perm change, even when you move the mouse away, until another row is clicked, the reason for this is, when a row is clicked it open that record up, so you can then tell which record you are viewing at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Priority of general definition `tr:nth-child(even)` is higher than class like `highlight1`. However, you cam trick by coloring the cells of selected / clicked row. See the sample below:

```js
$("#div2 tr").click(function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('highlight2');  
    $(this).addClass('highlight2');
});

$('#div2 tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight1');
  
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight1');  
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.highlight1 td {
    background-color: #FFD6F5;
}
.highlight2 td {
    background-color: #CEF6CE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>bbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
      <td>eeee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>bbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
      <td>eeee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>bbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
      <td>eeee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>bbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
      <td>eeee</td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work Skydiver, but unless you have a specific reason for reacting to the hover event in JavaScript you can simply use CSS to style the hover. I'd recommend combining Alexanders example with abhiklpms.

You will need to set the row background colour on the click event to set the colour permanently if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo using css only, click and hold the row to see the color on click.

```css
.tftable {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    width:100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #729ea5;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tftable th {
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:#acc8cc;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #729ea5;
    text-align:left;
}
.tftable tr {
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
.tftable td {
    font-size:12px;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #729ea5;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
 .tftable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
 .tftable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #dae5f4;
}
.tftable tr:hover {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.tftable tr:active {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:1 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:1 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:1 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:1 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:1 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:2 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:2 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:2 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:2 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:2 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:3 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:3 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:3 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:3 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:3 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:4 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:4 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:4 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:4 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:4 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:5 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:5 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:5 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:5 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:5 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row:6 Cell:1</td>
        <td>Row:6 Cell:2</td>
        <td>Row:6 Cell:3</td>
        <td>Row:6 Cell:4</td>
        <td>Row:6 Cell:5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```